# How can I install web3 globally in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: npm, ubuntu-16.04, web3js

I am trying to install web3 via npm.
`sudo npm install -g web3`
But I faced below error.

```
tom@ubuntu:/$ sudo npm install -g web3
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise 
Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been 
deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: 
https://npmjs.com/tar
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b browserifyCompatible 
git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git 
/home/tom/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-
clone-d38db07b
npm ERR! /home/tom/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d38db07b/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tom/.npm/_logs/2018-02-07T14_42_37_459Z-debug.log
```

How can I install web3?

Comment: Did you look in the log?

Comment: Yes, I will show you

785 verbose node v8.9.4
786 verbose npm  v5.6.0
787 error code 1
788 error Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b browserifyCompatible git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git /home/tom/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8a00e23
788 error /home/tom/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f8a00e23/.git: Permission denied
789 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Well, there's your error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your local `.npm` permissions are messed up. Just remove NPM cache by running:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/tom/.npm
```

and then try again.